# Ignore unknown functions in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

When rendering a Jinja2 template, either something like:

- `"hello {{world}}"`
- `"hello {{get_world()}}"`

I am interested in simply "passing along" any templated variables or functions that are not provided to Jinja. For example, if the variable `{{world}}` does not exist in the context, I want the output to keep `{{world}}`. If the the function `{{get_world()}}` does not exist in the context, I want to keep `{{get_world()}}`.

The closest I've gotten is with the following:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, BaseLoader, DebugUndefined

template = Environment(loader=BaseLoader, undefined=DebugUndefined).from_text("my template")
```

However, this above only works with the example `"hello {{world}}"`, but not the example `"hello {{get_world()}}"`. How can I achieve this functionality for both of these cases?